# Is there anyway to stop someone from seeing I’m online when I’m playing Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I started playing Minecraft with my young nephew and then set up a second account for myself and from that I started a realm that we both play on.

I didn’t think this through very well, because we’re now friends on both my accounts but sometimes I just want to play on my own. He’s only 9 and quite immature in some ways so saying “sorry, I just want to play on my own” is not a good option.

If I unfriend him on one of my accounts will he still be able to see when I’m playing? How do I block him?  I don’t just want to block him from joining me, I want to block him from even seeing that I’m playing. (I don’t want to block him from the realm, just from seeing my other account is still active).

I really don’t want to have to create a 3rd account - I’m quite attached to some of my worlds.

I play on an iPad with whatever Minecraft version is on the App Store.

Comment: Accounts does not equal worlds; they are completely separate. Also does just turning on appear offline not work?

Answer (score 3):

If you go into the guide menu (or the Xbox Game Bar on Windows), and select your profile, you can change your online status from "Online" to "Appear Offline".

As the status name suggests, it *makes you appear offline*. Game time will still tick, but if anyone (friend or not) looks up your profile, they'll see you as offline, even if you're standing in front of them in-game.

Comment: Works from Xbox app if you aren't playing on Windows.